# How to make an alias in .htaccess to change a local URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, alias

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate but I just don't know how to find the answer to this simple problem.

So I have a local page like this:

`http://example.com/mypage.php`

And all I want to do is to have anyone who tries to access `http://example.com/subfolder/mypage.php` to actually load the page at the above location.

I don't want a redirect. `http://example.com/subfolder/mypage.php` does not exist as an actual path on my server, but I want to make it available via rule in .htaccess

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*) /$1
```

This rule rewrites every request that starts with `/subfolder/` to `/`. Or if you need only for a specific URL-path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/mypage.php /mypage.php
```

Comment: yes, this works, but I only want that specific .php page, not for every request that starts with `subfolder`. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/(.*)   /$2
```

or use directly in httpd.conf like

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all  
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/(.*)   /$2    
</Directory>
```

**use $1 to get subfolder and $2 to get mypage.php :)**